# knockout multiple settings in data-bind tag (attr and style)

Tags: knockout.js

Till the "style: {" the syntax is good, what is wrong with 2nd part ?

```
<div data-bind="attr: { 'style': 'position:relative; float:left; width: ' + width + 
'; height: ' + height + ';} style: {border: $parent.foo() ? \'1px solid black\' : \'1px solid white\' }'">
```

Thanks in advance
Cs

Comment: Any errors in console?

Comment: I get unexpected identifier;

Comment: A missing comma & quote . its always better to keep static content out of data-bind and work like this http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/X82aC/1244/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use string concatenation for the model values. You are also missing a single quote at the end of the first `style` value and a comma at then end of the `attr` value:

```
<div data-bind="attr: { 'style': 'position:relative; float:left; width: width; height: height; '}, style: {border: $parent.foo() ? '1px solid black' : '1px solid white' }">
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hp7bzx8t/)

Comment: unfortunately this part is part of concatenated string and I cant use ' directly, I tried to use \' but it doesn't work. (for the sake of simplicity I left out the concatenated part)

Comment: Can you please update the question to have the concatenated part so I can provide the correct answer then.

Comment: Im going to try it without concatenation, thanks for your help really.